# Encode json in PHP file

Tags: php, json, mysqli, pdo

Actually i did the JSON encode in my php file(Working PHP) and it's working but when i follow the same step in the another PHP(Error PHP) file than it's not working Please Help me

**Error PHP**

```
<?php

require_once('dbConnect.php');
$id =$_POST['id'];
$sql= "select title,description,image,price,cid FROM products a where a.cid='$id'";

$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result,array('title'=>$row['0'],
                                 'description'=>$row['1'],
                                 'image'=>$row['2'],
                                 'price'=>$row['3'],
                                )
        );
}
echo json_encode(($result));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And i know it's a very stupid Question But i don't why Erro.php file is not Working and when i Hard Code **$id** in Query than Error.php works 
**EDIT**: Delete Working php

Comment: Try using prepared statements.

Comment: check the value `var_dump($_POST['id'])`.

Comment: i m newbie in php can you provide me the some example

Comment: delete Comment my mistake the Result is NULL

Comment: Check if `mysqli_query()` don't return `false`.

Comment: Did you add semi colon after that line ?

Comment: $id =$_POST['8'];
var_dump($id);
REsult is NULL []

Comment: @AlFoиceѫ the result is object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Sorry, I give up. You need to go through some basic tutorials of PHP first. Why did you put `$_POST['8']` ?

Comment: Sorry if i did some wrong 
$id =$_POST['id'];
i just thought may i it's works after hard code

Comment: WHat is not working?

Comment: Downvoted for thinking "its not working" is a useful diagnostic. Why are you using POST for an idempotent request?

Comment: $id =$_POST['id'];
$sql= "select title,description,image,price,cid FROM products a where a.cid='$id'";
In the above line if i hard code a.cid='8' then error.php file is working perfectly and if i not the it shows **[]** @RiggsFolly

Comment: Then `$_POST['id']` does not contain 8 or any valid data

Answer (score 1):

Then we have to assume `$_POST['id']` either does not exist or does not contain valid data or the query has an error in it.

You should code anything like this to at least report such conditions in a usable way like this for example

```
<?php

require_once('dbConnect.php');

if ( ! isset($_POST['id']) ) {
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>'Input missing'));
    exit;
}

$_POST['id'];

// amend select to select only what you want
$sql= "select title,description,image,price
        FROM products
        where cid = '$id'";

$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if ( ! $res ) {
    echo json_encode(array( 'status'=>false, 
                            'msg'=>'Query failed',
                            'sql_msg' => mysqli_error($con)
                            )
                    );
    exit;
}

$result = array();

// use mysqli_fetch_assoc() and the columns names are used
// so you can simply add the $row to the $result array
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $result[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode(array('status'=>true, 'results'=>$result));
?>
```

Now make a small amendment to your javascript so it first checks for the status, and while testing show any error messages.

Comment: thank you now i understand my POST value is null so that's why i face this problem....

Comment: my input is like **"{"id":"1"}"** (encoded in jsonObject)

Comment: Ok, sorry not clear. Is `$_POST['id'] = "{"id":"1"}"` or is `$_POST = "{"id":"1"}"`

Comment: i think it's a key value pair so i change my php 
$stripe_json = json_decode($_POST['id']);
$ida=$stripe_json->id;

$sql= "select title,description,image,price,cid FROM products a where a.cid='".$ida."'";

But still not working

Comment: Add a `print_r($_POST);` to your code what does that show

Comment: Maybe you should also show us the javascript that sends the data to this script

Comment: Mission Complete problem Solve Thanx Sir